# Multiple inheritance for Quality Profiles

Tags: sonarqube

I see a need for multiple inheritance for Quality Profiles to avoid unnecessary manual work when we upgrade.

For example we would like to inherit all rules from  "Sonar Way" and from "Android Lint" and restore the built-in profiles after each upgrade, making sure we are always up to date.

Is this feature planned for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is not planned for the moment - even though it has already been discussed a couple of times.

Multiple inheritance offers some good features that we can understand. Your use case is a good example. But it also brings complexity when it comes to decide what to do when you inherit the same rule from 2 quality profiles and this rule is activated differently on those 2 profiles.

Comment: One, in my mind, reasonable approach to the "deadly Diamond of Death" problem would be not to allow it. 
That the Quality Profile with multiple rule inheritance is considered broken until it's made unambiguous.

Comment: Indeed, but then this means adding lots of validation when you update any quality profile => what happens when you update profile A and this makes profile Z ambiguous because it somehow inherits from A?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it would be good to detect any such errors early.

A less strict approach would be to skip any ambiguous rules during analysis (with a warning/error message)

Answer (score 1):

There is still a workaround  : if you use the same `sonar.projectKey` but select a different profile at each scan, issues will always be associated to this key so results from different scans will all be aggregated in the same project.

Comment: Will metrics, such as code coverage, still remain from the previous scan?